# Why might xunit.net say "Specified method is not supported"

Tags: xunit.net

When I try to run my xUnit.net tests, I get this error:

```
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.63]     xunit.UnitTest1.TestTheAnswer [FAIL]
  Failed xunit.UnitTest1.TestTheAnswer [1 ms]
  Error Message:
   System.NotSupportedException : Specified method is not supported.
```

What might cause this error?

Answer (score 8):

TL;DR: `public`

---

So, another reason for this error is that the property/field/method
must be `public`, which might not be obvious.

The popup help only mentions that the member must be `static` and that the return value must be compatible with `IEnumerable<object[]>`. It says nothing about the access modifier. The error message when running, as stated in the question, is also not helpful in this regard.

(I'm on `xunit` version 2.4.1 and tried to use a `private` property, which failed. Solved by making the property `public`.)

Comment: I am facing this issue even with public modifier !

Comment: I see that you provided your own answer, @kuldeep . Nice find!

Answer (score 4):

In my case I was missing the static keyword when defining the test data:

```
public static IEnumerable<object[]> AdminDevicesFetchActionTestData() {...}
 
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(AdminDevicesFetchActionTestData))]
public async Task HandleAsync_AdminDevicesFetchAction_ShouldReturnValidResponse(AdminDevicesFetchAction action,
    AdminDevicesResponse expectedResponse)
{
```

Answer (score 3):

Just in case if anyone else face this issue. In my case I had a public static method as following.

```
public static IEnumerable<object[]> MyTestDataSet(string name, short testData)
{
    yield return new object[]
    {
        TestDataBuilder.BuildTestConfiguration(name),
        TestDataBuilder.GetEntityWithTestData(testData),
    };
}

internal static TestEntity GetEntityWithTestData(short param)
{
  //returns entity by assigning param to one of its properties defined as short.
}
```

What did not work for me :

```
[MemberData(nameof(MyTestDataSet), "TestName", 800)]
```

What finally worked for me :

```
[MemberData(nameof(MyTestDataSet), "TestName", (short)800)]
```

It seems the static method param type must be exactly how it is defined (short in this case) and there is no default casting.

Also, I hope this may be useful for somebody who face this issue in future.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a typo in the `MemberData` attribute parameter. Here is an example:

```
public static object[][] MyTestIntegers =>
    new[] { 0, 1, 42, 9999999 }
        .Select(i => new object[] { i })
        .ToArray();

[Theory]
[MemberData("MyTestIntgers")]
public void TestTheAnswer(int i) =>
    Assert.NotEqual(42, i);
```

`[MemberData("MyTestIntgers")]` should be `[MemberData("MyTestIntegers")]`

Comment: you should be able to use`nameof` to sidestep that...